# Map form values to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, http-get

I have a particular form on my page with multiple input values and a button.  Example:

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
<input type="text" id="blah1" value="blah" />
<input type="hidden" id="blah2" value="blah2" />
</form>
<button type="button" id="awesomeButton">Click for Link</button>
<div id="link">http://mysite.com/?blah1=blah&blah2=blah2</div>
```

I want to find an easy way to make it so when someone clicks the button on my website, it looks at all the form values and generates a link which is exactly the same as if the form was set to use method="get" and submitted.  So if they click "awesomeButton", then it'll generate a link and show it to the person, such as http://mysite.com/?blah1=blah&blah2=blah2

Does anybody know an easy way to grab the values from the form and make a link?

Something like...

```
$('button#awesomeButton').click(function()
{
//Grab all form elements, maybe something like var blah = $('#myForm :input'); ??
var link = ???;//Generate a link somehow
$('div#link').html(link);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use a library like jQuery or dojo that will do the job for you. In jQuery for example:

```
$("#myForm").serialize();
```

The documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

In dojo:

```
dijit.byId('myForm').get('value');
```

[Follow this link](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `id`s are `name`s, you want `.serialize()`:

```
var link = "http://.../?" + $("#myForm").serialize();
```